# Symfony2 / SonataUserBundle - Automatic Login after Registration

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle

In my project I use Symfony 2.8, the SonataAdminBundle and the SonataUserBundle.

I override the registerAction of the RegistrationController in the FOSUserBundle. After a successful registration I want that the User is automatically logged in in the SonataAdmin backend.

After handle my registration I call this in the Action:

```
$userManager->updateUser($user);
$response = new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('sonata_admin_dashboard'));
$this->authenticateUser($user, $response);
$this->setFlash('notice', 'success!');
return $response;
```

My FOSUser config looks like this:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: admin
    user_class: Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User
    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: false
        form:
            validation_groups: [pwValidation]
```

And my `security.yml` looks like this:

```
firewalls:
        admin:
            pattern:            /admin/(.*)
            context:            admin
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /admin/login
                use_forward:    true
                check_path:     /admin/login_check
                failure_path:   null
                default_target_path: /admin/dashboard
                always_use_default_target_path: true
            logout:
                path:           /admin/logout
            anonymous:          true
```

Every time I register a new User I get redirected to the SonataAdmin Login Screen with an 401 Statuscode and the Symfony profiler says I'm authenticated with an AnonymousToken.

I already tried to skip the function

```
$this->authenticateUser($user, $response);
```

and manually call this:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'admin', $user->getRoles());
$this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
$this->container->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
```

But if I try this I get the same behavior.

Can some tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason why the automatic authentication is not working.
The problem was that my `/register` route was not behind the firewall where I want to authenticate the user.
I changed the route to `/admin/register`and set the `access_control` settings for this route to:

```
-{ path: ^/admin/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

After that the user is authenticated correctly with calling the method `$this->authenticateUser($user, $response);`